# How do I write a Python program that computes the average from a .dat file?

Tags: statistics

I have this so far but I don't know how to write over the .dat file:

```
def main():
   fname = input("Enter filename:")
   infile = open(fname, "r")
   data = infile.read()
   print(data)

for line in infile.readlines():
    score = int(line)
    counts[score] = counts[score]+1
    infile.close()

total=0
for c in enumerate(counts):
    total = total + i*c
    average = float(total)/float(sum(counts))
print(average) 
main()
```

Here is my .dat file:

```
4
3
5
6
7
```

My statistics professor expects us to learn Python to compute the mean and standard deviation. All I need to know is how to do the mean and then I've got the rest figured out. I want to know how does Python write over each line in a .dat file. Could someone tell me how to fix this code? I've never done programming before.

Comment: But this is for my statistics class. This is relevant for my understanding to do well in the class. Thanks for the reference though.

Comment: This is not a mathematics question. You might as well be trying to do file IO with files containing recipes. Would that prompt you to ask such a question on the cooking site?

Comment: Sorry. I will not ask a programming-related question here.

Comment: Why don't someone here just move the question to StackOverflow for him?

Comment: @Karl: Only moderators can do that and you should be able to flag the question to bring it to their attention.

Comment: @KannappanSampath: I am more surprised by the upvote than by the downvote. Downvotes are for the _content_. They in no way reflect any hostility towards the person posting the content. In this case, this content is clearly off-topic (and unsalvagable to become on-topic) and downvotes serve (their intended purpose) to increase the signal/noise ratio. If people pity upvote bad content, this is encouragement to post more noise. In any case, downvoting is subjective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, as I understand it, in three parts:

*How to read the file in*

in your example you use

> infile.read()

which reads the entire contents of the file into a string and takes you to the end of file. Therefore the following

> infile.readlines()

will read nothing more. You should omit the first read().

*How to compute the mean*

There are many ways to do this in python - more or less elegant - and also I guess it depends on exactly what the problem is. But in the simplest case you can just sum and count the values as you go , then divide sum by count at the end to get the result:

```
infile = open("d.dat", "r")
total = 0.0
count = 0
for line in infile.readlines():    
    print ("reading in line: ",line)
    try:
        line_value = float(line)
        total += line_value
        count += 1
        print ("value = ",line_value, "running total =",total, "valid lines read = ",count)
    except:
        pass #skipping non-numeric lines or characters

infile.close()
```

The try/except part is just in case you have lines or characters in the file that can't be turned into floats, these will be skipped.

*How to write to the .dat file*

Finally you seem to be asking how to write the result back out to the d.dat file. Not sure whether you really need to do this, it should be acceptable to just display the result as in the above code. However if you do need to write it back to the same file, just close it after reading from it,  reopen it for writing (in 'append' mode so output goes to the end of the file), and output the result using write().

```
outfile = open("d.dat","a")
outfile.write("\naverage = final total / number of data points = " + str(total/count)+"\n")
outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fname = input("Enter filename:")
infile = open(fname, "r")
data = infile.readline() #Reads first line
print(data)
data = infile.readline() #Reads second line
print(data)
```

You can put this in a loop.

Also, these values will come in as `Strings` convert them to floats using `float(data)` each time.

Also, the guys over at StackOverflow are not as bad at math as you think. This could have easily been answered there. (And maybe in a better fashion)